# Extracting data from a file read in with Pandas

Tags: python, file, pandas

I believe that I have successfully read in my files with a "for loop" as shown in the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

filename = glob.glob('1511**.mnd')
data_nov15_hereford = pd.DataFrame()
frames = []

for i in filename:
  f_nov15_hereford = pd.read_csv(i, skiprows = 33, sep='\s+')
  frames.append(f_nov15_hereford)
data_nov15_hereford = pd.concat(frames)
data_nov15_hereford = data_nov15_hereford.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
```

My problem now is that I want to take out some information from the files. Specifically I want the 80 m wind speed from the files. When I read in just one file, instead of looping over multiple files the code works like I need it to by simply doing this:

```
height = data_nov15_hereford['#']
wspd = data_nov15_hereford["z"]
hub = np.where(height==80)
print hub
hub_wspd = wspd[5:4582:32]
```

hub_wspd is the 80 m wind speed that I am interested in. And I get the index numbers 5:4582 by printing out hub. And then all I have to do is skip every 32 rows to continue to pull out the 80 m wind speed from the file. However, now that I have read in multiple files (that all look the same and have the same layout as this one file) I can't seem to pull out the 80 m wind speed the same way. Basically, I print out hub and get the indices 5:65418 and then I skip every 32 rows but when I print out the tail end of the hub_wspd it doesn't match the file so I must be doing something wrong. Any ideas why it isn't working with multiple files but worked with the single file? I can also attach a copy of the single data file if that would help. Thanks!

Comment: Try `data_nov15_hereford = pd.concat(frames, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: If the files aren't a multiple of 32 lines long, you're going to be picking up some offsets as you cycle through them. Is there a reason you can't just grab the data from each file individually before concatenating all of them?

Comment: I could try grabbing the data from each file individually before concatenating all of them to see if that works but I am not sure how to go about that. Suggestions?

Comment: Because when I try to move these commands pulling out the 80 m wspd data before the concat statement but after the append statement, then when I print out the 80 m wspd I only get the last file and not all of the files.

Comment: There's your problem. You should be doing the slicing in the loop, _before_ the append.

Comment: Alternatively, something like `hub_wspd = data_nov15_hereford[data_nov15_hereford['#'] == 80].z` after the `concat` might work. You really don't need to do the slicing manually. You should also read up on how indexing works in numpy anyways. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: Wow slicing is not as difficult as I was making it! Thanks for the link! Also I found two ways to get this to work. Your suggestion worked and not slicing manually also worked. Thanks for your help!